# return value from batch script

Tags: batch-file, exit-code

I am calling batch script from vbscript.

In the batch script, based on condition I want to return custom exit code.

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`
for /f "usebackq" %%i in (`"%1"\fciv.exe" -md5 %2"`) do set md5_1=%%i  
for /f "usebackq" %%i in (`"%1"\fciv.exe" -md5 %3"`) do set md5_2=%%i

if "!md5_1!" == "!md5_2!" (  
    set md5_1=  
    set md5_2=  
    exit 0  
) else (  
    set md5_1=  
    set md5_2=  
    exit 1  
)
endlocal
```

I am getting value 0 for both of the conditions.

can anybody help me?

Comment: It works fine for me. Post your script.

Comment: @echo off setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION for /f "usebackq" %%i in (`"%1"\fciv.exe" -md5 %2"`) do set md5_1=%%i for /f "usebackq" %%i in (`"%1"\fciv.exe" -md5 %3"`) do set md5_2=%%i if "!md5_1!" == "!md5_2!" ( set md5_1= set md5_2= exit 0 ) else ( set md5_1= set md5_2= exit 1 ) endlocal
The code actually generates checksum for two files and returns 0 if they are same, returns 1 if they are different

Comment: You can edit your question to add the code in. Also, you need to use `exit /b <error code>`

Comment: Even for false condition i am getting exit code as 0. How to get exit code 1 ?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your error. Sorry.

Comment: put `echo %md5_1% # %md5_2%` after the second for-loop and post the values.

Answer (score 4):

The batch processor (cmd) will actually retain the errorlevel of the last call.
To use this feature, do not call `endlocal` at the end of the script,
this is [called implicitly anyway<sup>MSDN</sup>](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490898.aspx)
Besides, always use `exit /b` inside scripts, as the normal exit call will also exit the current batch processor instance

Answer (score 0):

Both your commands look to have mismatched quotes and can fail with long names.  Try this

You aren't used delayed expansion and nulling the variables is pointless when a setlocal has been issued.

Usebackq is not needed.

Finally it's bad practice to use %%i because it looks so much like %%l and %%1
Microsoft uses it in examples, I know.

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f %%a in ('"%~1\fciv.exe" -md5 "%~2"') do set md5_1=%%a  
for /f %%a in ('"%~1\fciv.exe" -md5 "%~3"') do set md5_2=%%a

if "%md5_1%"=="%md5_2%" (exit /b 0) else (exit /b 1 )
endlocal
```